# Solution of $\dot x=F(x) + \nabla V(x)$ also solution of $\dot x = F(x)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $F\in \mathcal C^1(\Bbb R^N,\Bbb R^N)$ be a vector field and $V(x) \in\mathcal C^1(\Bbb R^N) $ potential with $F(x) \cdot \nabla V(x)= 0 \forall x \in \Bbb R^N$ and $F(x):\mathbb{R}^N\to \mathbb{R}^N $ and $x:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$.
>
> Let $x$ be periodic solution of $\dot x=F(x) + \nabla V(x)$.
>
> Show $x$ is also soultion of $\dot x = F(x)$

Edit:
I'm sorry, this is how the problem was formulated , I just know that V(x) is the potential energy of the hamilton function.

> Let $x$ be a t-periodic solution of $\dot x=F(x) + \nabla V(x)$ and let $a(t)=V(x)$ than:

$\dot a(t)=\nabla V(x(t))\cdot \dot x(t) =\nabla V(x(t)) (F(x) + \nabla V(x)) = |V(x(t))|^2 \ge 0$

Comment: $F$ is vector valued, there is no inverse operation and no square.

Comment: Some things to try: 1) "Square" the ODE to get an identity for $\|\dot{x}\|^2 = \ldots$. 2) Try to dot the ODE with $\dot{x}$ and rewrite the right hand side using $\frac{dV}{dt} = \dot{x}\cdot \nabla V$ on the last term and $\dot{x} = [F(x) - \nabla V]$ on the first term. 3) Combind what you got

Comment: The problem is badly formulated. Is $x:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R^N$? (Then $\nabla V$ is more or less ininfluent). Is $x:\mathbb R\times\mathbb R^N \to \mathbb R^N\quad (t,\xi)\mapsto x(t,\xi)$ and $\nabla V(x)=\nabla_\xi x(\xi)\cdot\nabla V$? (more complicated)

Comment: @LutzL : Haven't thought of that - thanks !

Comment: @Winther : Thanks !

Comment: @guestDiego: Sorry, I don't know

Comment: The only formulation that makes any sense here is $x(t) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ and $F(x):\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ though it doesn't hurt to make this explict in the question.

Comment: @Winther: Do you mean the second derivative of with "dot the ODE" ?

Comment: No, I mean to take the dot-product, i.e. $\dot{x} \cdot \dot{x} = \dot{x} \cdot [F + \nabla V]$. Also by "squaring" I mean to take the norm of each side of the ODE.

Comment: Ah ! :) Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
\frac{d}{dt}V(x(t))=∇V(x(t))·\dot x(t)=∇V(x(t))·F(x(t))+\|∇V(x(t))\|^2.
$$
Over a period $[0,T]$ of $x$ that integrates to
$$
0=V(x(T))-V(x(0))=\int_0^T\|∇V(x(t))\|^2\,dt
$$
which can only happen if $∇V(x(t))=0$ along the trajectory.

Comment: Thank you Lutz, sorry that I formulated the question so complicated.